# Labeling data in ListPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, labeling

I have the following coordinate pairs:

```
c={{1137, 1008}, {1052, 991}, {1060, 988}, {1137, 1007}, 
  {1189, 1090}, {1125, 1049}, {1189, 1081}, {1248, 1128}, 
  {1251, 1095}, {1129, 1007}, {1016, 964}, {1132, 1059}}
```

and corresponding labels:

```
labels = {"a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e", "f", "f"};
```

What I want to do:

> 1. Plotting coordinates as points with `ListPlot`
> 2. Plotting arrows between coordinate pairs
> 3. Plotting corresponding label and coordinate of each point as text

I tried the following:

```
plot = ListPlot[c, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Point[{0, 0}]}]}, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"x", ""}}, ImageSize -> Medium];

arrows = Partition[c, 2];

gArrows = Graphics@Arrow[a] /. a -> arrows;

Show[plot, gArrows]
```

The result is:

[image]

I would like to plot close to each point its label and coordinate.

For the left lower point I added this manually:

[image]

**How can all coordinates and labels be added automatically to the data points?**

Comment: Does [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126855/how-to-customize-point%C2%B4s-labels-in-a-scatter-plot) help? (Not the answer, 'cause it's about styling, but the approach in the question itself.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can take the advantage of new labeling function:

```
plot = ListPlot[c, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
    PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Point[{0, 0}]}]}, 
    FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"x", ""}}, ImageSize -> 500,     
    LabelingFunction -> (Placed[ToString@labels[[#2[[1]]]] <> " " <>
    ToString[#], Automatic] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Great ... thank you. What does `labels[[#2[[1]]]]` ?

Comment: seems that LabelingFunction didn't work with ListPlot in Mma10.0.2

Comment: With Mathematica 11.3 this does not work any more: Always "a" is showed as first part of the labels. Can you reproduce that?

Comment: Hi @lio, since 11.3, the structure of data in LabelingFunction has been extended to include which dataset it belongs to. Change it to `labels[[#2[[2]]]]` will do. `#2[[1]]` is always 1 in this case.

Answer (score 8):

`Callout` formatted with `Grid`

```
With[{g = Partition[c, 2], lbs = labels[[1 ;; ;; 2]], 
  col = ColorData[97]},
 ListPlot[
  Append[
    MapIndexed[Callout[Style[Mean@#1, col@First@#2],
        Grid[
         Prepend[{"", "x", "y"}]@
          MapThread[
           Prepend, {#1, Table[Subscript[lbs[[First@#2]], i], {i, 2}]}], 
         BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> Small}, 
         Dividers -> {{2 -> Gray}, {2 -> Gray}}], 
        Background -> None] &]@g]@g,
  ColorFunction -> col,
  PlotStyle -> Append[Opacity[0]]@ConstantArray[Automatic, Length@g],
  Prolog -> MapIndexed[{col@First@#2, Arrow@#1} &, g]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also with `TableForm`

```
With[{g = Partition[c, 2], lbs = labels[[1 ;; ;; 2]], 
  col = ColorData[97]},
 ListPlot[
  Append[
    MapIndexed[Callout[Style[Mean@#1, col@First@#2],
        TableForm[#1, 
         TableHeadings -> {Table[Subscript[lbs[[First@#2]], i], {i, 2}], {"x", "y"}}, 
         TableSpacing -> {1, .5}, TableAlignments -> Center], 
        Background -> None] &]@g]@g,
  ColorFunction -> col,
  PlotStyle -> Append[Opacity[0]]@ConstantArray[Automatic, Length@g],
  Prolog -> MapIndexed[{col@First@#2, Arrow@#1} &, g]]
 ]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect ... this is publication ready ... thanks a lot

Comment: How is it possible NOT to show a point at the center of each arrow?

Comment: @mrz Add `PlotStyle -> Append[Opacity[0]]@ConstantArray[Automatic, Length@g]` to the `ListPlot` options.