# How can I display points with their coordinates?

Tags: graphics, labeling

```
Garfield = {
    Graphics[Line[{{1,3},{1,5},{2,6},{2,9},{3,10},{4,10},{5,9},{5.5,8},{6,9},{7,10},{8,10},{9,9},{9,6},{10,5},{10,3},{9,2},{7,1},{4,1},{2,2},{1,3}}]],
    Graphics[Line[{{2.5,3.5},{3,4},{3.5,3},{4.5,3},{5.5,4},{6.5,3},{7.5,3},{8,4},{8.5,3.5}}]],
    Graphics[Line[{{5,4},{6,4},{6,4.5},{5,4.5},{5,4}}]],
    Graphics[Line[{{8.5,3.5},{9,3.5},{9,4.5},{2,4.5},{2,3.5},{2.5,3.5}}]],
    Graphics[Line[{{3,4.5},{5,4.5},{5,7},{3,7},{3,4.5}}]],
    Graphics[Line[{{6,4.5},{8,4.5},{8,7},{6,7},{6,4.5}}]],
    Graphics[Line[{{4,5},{4.5,5},{4.5,6},{4,6},{4,5}}]],
    Graphics[Line[{{6.5,5},{7,5},{7,6},{6.5,6},{6.5,5}}]],
    Graphics[Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, {1, 3}}]
};


Show[Garfield, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

It displays fine, but with no `Point` in red. How do I get each point to display and with their coordinates like this?

[image]

**Additionally**

It would seem a bit excessive to show (x,y) for **all** points, could we make something more `flexible` like,

```
...
...
Graphics[Line[{showp{8.5,3.5},{9,3.5},{9,4.5},showp{2,4.5},{2,3.5},{2.5,3.5}}]],
...
...
```

where we use `showp` to indicate we want to show these points in that particular segment of drawing?

Thanks.

Comment: @m_goldberg Sorry can't see you comment, but I did get a notification on my app on the phone ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Callout` can help you position the labels. I will let you experiment with the options so that the display gets right, but here is a start:

```
coords = {{1, 3}, {1, 5}, {2, 6}, {2, 9}, {3, 10}, {4, 10}, {5, 9}, {5.5, 8}, {6, 9}, {7, 10}, {8, 10}, {9, 9}, {9, 6}, {10, 5}, {10, 3}, {9, 2}, {7, 1}, {4, 1}, {2, 2}};
callouts = Callout[#, #] & /@ coords;
ListPlot[callouts, Prolog -> Line[Append[coords, {1, 3}]], ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I am looking at this on my iPad, just a very crude observation here, did {1,3} get "covered up" by {1,5}? I assume that's what you want me to experiment with? Otherwise this random "position" seem ok.

Comment: In comparison, {10,3} and {10,5} are living in harmony:)

Comment: Why add the completely unnecessary ToString?

Comment: @ChenStatsYu The point {1,3} doesn't get a callout because it is duplicated (it is the first and last point of `coords`).

Comment: @ChenStatsYu I have fixed the issue with the missing point in the way suggested by Carl.

Comment: @CarlWoll You're right, thank you. `ToString` was there because I had been experimenting with more arguments, and then it is necessary. Compare f.e. `Callout[#, #, Automatic, #] & /@ coords;` and `Callout[#, ToString[#], Automatic, #] & /@ coords;` The first only shows the first number.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the idea of displaying the coordinates alongside the points. Positioning them is tricky and the drawing quickly becomes very cluttered. So I suggest labeling the points with tooltips that will only appear when the mouse cursor moves a point.

The necessary modification to your code is simple

```
Garfield = 
  {Graphics[Line[{{1, 3}, {1, 5}, {2, 6}, {2, 9}, {3, 10}, {4, 10}, {5, 9}, {5.5, 8}, {6, 9}, {7, 10}, {8, 10}, {9, 9}, {9, 6}, {10, 5}, {10, 3}, {9, 2}, {7, 1}, {4, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 3}}]], 
   Graphics[Line[{{2.5, 3.5}, {3, 4}, {3.5, 3}, {4.5, 3}, {5.5, 4}, {6.5, 3}, {7.5, 3}, {8, 4}, {8.5, 3.5}}]], 
   Graphics[Line[{{5, 4}, {6, 4}, {6, 4.5}, {5, 4.5}, {5, 4}}]], 
   Graphics[Line[{{8.5, 3.5}, {9, 3.5}, {9, 4.5}, {2, 4.5}, {2, 3.5}, {2.5, 3.5}}]], 
   Graphics[Line[{{3, 4.5}, {5, 4.5}, {5, 7}, {3, 7}, {3, 4.5}}]], 
   Graphics[Line[{{6, 4.5}, {8, 4.5}, {8, 7}, {6, 7}, {6, 4.5}}]], 
   Graphics[Line[{{4, 5}, {4.5, 5}, {4.5, 6}, {4, 6}, {4, 5}}]], 
   Graphics[Line[{{6.5, 5}, {7, 5}, {7, 6}, {6.5, 6}, {6.5, 5}}]]};

pts = {{1, 3}, {3, 4}};

Show[
  Garfield,
  Graphics @ Tooltip[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[#]}, #] & /@ pts,
  Frame -> True]
```

[image: garfield]

Of course, you need to modify `pts` to be the list of all the points you want to show.

If you don't like my solution using tooltips, which is quick and easy, you might want to look at a more elaborate solution I offer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132519/3066) that will allow you to put the coordinates anywhere you like.

Note: `Graphics` does not accept the `Epilog` option because it is never needed. `Epilog` is for `Plot` and its relatives.

Comment: The `PointSize` and color does not need to be repeated for each point. `Show[Garfield, 
 Graphics@{PointSize[Large], Red, Tooltip[Point[#], #] & /@ pts}, 
 Frame -> True]`

Comment: `pts = Flatten[Garfield[[All, 1, 1]], 1];` to do it simply for all points of `Garfied`.