# Plotting Ordered Pairs with Labels

Tags: plotting, labeling

**Question:** How would one recreate a plot similar to the one below?

> [image]

- Notice that the points are labelled.
- To keep things easy, suppose our points are $(1,1)$ with label "point1" and $(1, 2)$ with label "point2". (This means the plot can't modeled as a function, since $1$ appears in the domain twice).

Comment: Related and possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132268/

Answer (score 5):

There are two methods: `Labeled` or `Callout`, as follows:

```
ListPlot[{Labeled[{94, 1}, "lisbon"], Labeled[{89, 87}, "antwerp"], 
  Labeled[{7, 33}, "boston"], Labeled[{30, 26}, "edinburgh"], 
  Labeled[{32, 60}, "lima"]}]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[{Callout[{94, 1}, "lisbon"], Callout[{89, 87}, "antwerp"], 
  Callout[{7, 33}, "boston"], Callout[{30, 26}, "edinburgh"], 
  Callout[{32, 60}, "lima"]}]
```

[image]

As you can see, the primary difference is the addition of callout lines. It should be noted, an avoidance algorithm is used and can result in some of the labels not being displayed as they're converted to `Tooltips`, e.g.

```
count = 100;
points = RandomInteger[{0, 100}, {count, 2}];
labels = "label " <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[count];
ListPlot[MapThread[Labeled, {points, labels}]] 
ListPlot[MapThread[Callout, {points, labels}]]
```

[image]