# Draw a figure made of lines and put labels on some

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to put $ \Delta y_{1} $ in the magenta line, $ \Delta y_{2} $ in both red lines, $ \Delta L $ in the yellow line and $ L $ in the line that is continuation of $ \Delta L $.

Either using my code or if there is a better way to do it.

```
d1 = Table[{i - 1, (j - 1)/2}, {i, 1}, {j, 3}];
d2 = Table[{i - 1, 1 + (j - 1)/2}, {i, 2, 2}, {j, 3}];
d3 = Join[d1, d2];
d = Transpose[d3];
g1 = ListLinePlot[d, PlotStyle -> Black, 
PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", 8}];
g2 = ListLinePlot[{{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 2}}}, 
PlotStyle -> Black];
g3 = ListLinePlot[{{1, 1.5}, {1.2, 1.7}}, PlotStyle -> Yellow];
g4 = ListLinePlot[{{1, 1.5}, {1.2, 1.5}}, PlotStyle -> Black];
g5 = ListLinePlot[{{1.2, 1.5}, {1.2, 1.7}}, PlotStyle -> Magenta];
g6 = ListLinePlot[{{1.2, 1.7}, {1.2, 1.95}}, PlotStyle -> Red];
g7 = ListLinePlot[{{0, 0.5}, {0, 0.75}}, PlotStyle -> Red];
g8 = ListLinePlot[{{1.2, 1.95}, {1.2, 1.95}}, PlotStyle -> Green, 
PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", 8}];
g9 = ListLinePlot[{{1, 1.5}, {1, 1.5}},    PlotStyle -> Green, 
PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", 8}];
Show[g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8, g9, Ticks -> None, Frame -> True,
FrameTicks -> {{{{0, "j=1"}, {1/2, "j=2"}, {(1/2) + (1/4), 
  "  \[VerticalEllipsis]  "}, {3/3, "j=N"}}, None}, {Automatic, 
False}}, PlotRange -> All, 
Epilog -> {Text[Style["\[CapitalDelta]x", 12], Scaled[{0.92, 0.68}]]}]
```

Comment: You realize you can condense all of your `ListLinePlot` calls into a single one with multiple `PlotStyle` args, right? And the points can all easily be added with `Epilog` and `Point`. The `\[CapitalDelta]x` and `\[CapitalDelta]y` can be stuck in the epilog too by using `Text` in its 4 argument form so that it rests above the line, centered on it, and pointing up the line as well. Presumably that should be enough for you, right?

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed because the answer is easy to find in the documentation. It isn't. This is actually a non-trivial question about drawing a diagram and labeling it. I am working on it but it will take some time before I post my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plotting functions like `ListLinePlot` are not very good for drawing diagrams like the one you are trying to draw. It is better to use `Graphics` for that purpose. Here is how I rewrote your code using `Graphics`.

#### Data

```
d1 = Table[{i - 1, (j - 1)/2}, {i, 1}, {j, 3}];
d2 = Table[{i - 1, 1 + (j - 1)/2}, {i, 2, 2}, {j, 3}];
pts = Transpose[Join[d1, d2]] // Catenate // N;
```

#### Graphics

```
Module[{p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10},
  p0 = {1, 0};
  {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6} = pts;
  p7 = {0, 0.75};
  p8 = {1.2, 1.5};
  p9 = {1.2, 1.7};
  p10 = {1.2, 1.95};
  Graphics[
    {AbsolutePointSize[6], AbsoluteThickness[2],
      {Darker[Yellow, .25], Line[{p4, p9}]},
      {Black,
         Line[{p1, p2}], Line[{p3, p4}], Line[{p5, p6}],
         Line[{p4, p8}], Line[{p1, p5}], Line[{p0, p6}]},
      {Red, Line[{p3, p7}], Line[{p8, p10}]}, ,
      {Black, Point[{p1, p2, p3, p5, p6}]},
      {Darker[Green, .25], Point[{p4, p10}]},
      Text["Δx", (p4 + p8)/2, {0, 1.5}],
      Text["Δy", (p8 + p9)/2, {-1.5, 0}],
      Text["Δy", (p3 + p7)/2, {-1.5, 0}],
      Text["L", (p3 + p4)/2, {0, 1.5}],
      Text["ΔL", (p4 + p9)/2, {0, -1.5}]},
    PlotRange -> {{-.05, 1.25}, Automatic},
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
    Frame -> True,
    FrameTicks -> 
      {{{{0, "j=1"}, {1/2, "j=2"}, {(1/2) + (1/4), "  ⋮  "}, {3/3, "j=N"}}, None},
       {Automatic, False}},
    ImageSize -> Large]]
```

[image: graphics]

I hope I have interpreted your question correctly and the above code produces the diagram you are trying to create.

Note: In the `Text` expressions I have used `Text`'s 3rd argument to nudge the labels so they do not sit right on the lines they are labelling. This is a common use of the 3rd argument.

#### Update

In case anyone is wondering how I kept track of which point was where in the graphic, perhaps I should confess that I first made this diagram:

```
Block[{p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10},
  p0 = {1, 0};
  {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6} = pts;
  p7 = {0, 0.75};
  p8 = {1.2, 1.5};
  p9 = {1.2, 1.7};
  p10 = {1.2, 1.95};
  Graphics[
    List @@
     (Text[SymbolName[Unevaluated[#]], #] & /@ 
        Unevaluated /@ Hold[p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10]),
    PlotRange -> {{-.05, 1.25}, Automatic},
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
    Frame -> True,
    ImageSize -> Large]]
```

[image: pts]

When building a diagram which requires me to track a lot of points, I fined making such an auxiliary diagram first a great help.

#### 2nd update

Although the the above code presents the way I generated labelled points when I began to work on this problem, the following method which had the virtue of being a bit simpler occurred to me. You may prefer to do it this way.

```
Block[{p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, lbls, allPts},
  lbls = SymbolName /@ {p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10};
  p0 = {1, 0};
  {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6} = pts;
  p7 = {0, 0.75};
  p8 = {1.2, 1.5};
  p9 = {1.2, 1.7};
  p10 = {1.2, 1.95};
  allPts = {p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10};
  Graphics[
    MapThread[Text[#1, #2] &, {lbls, allPts}],
    PlotRange -> {{-.05, 1.25}, Automatic},
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
    Frame -> True,
    ImageSize -> Large]]
```

This creates the same labelled point diagram as shown above.

#### 3rd update

Just for completeness, here is another way to write the `Text` expressions for the line segment labels:

```
Text["Δx", Offset[{0, -8}, (p4 + p8)/2]],
Text["Δy", Offset[{10, 0}, (p8 + p9)/2]],
Text["Δy", Offset[{10, 0}, (p3 + p7)/2]],
Text["L", Offset[{0, -10}, (p3 + p4)/2]],
Text["ΔL", Offset[{0, 8}, (p4 + p9)/2]]},
```

Here I am using `Offset` in the 2nd argument to do the nudging and omitting the 3rd argument. The offsets are expressed in printers points which some people find easier to visualize than the special local coordinate system used by the 3rd argument.

Comment: Just a suggestion:  If I'm not planning to re-generate the graphics from the code, I find it much easier to just  draw the labels somewhere on the plot, then click on the graphics and manually move the labels with the mouse for optimum positioning.  Works well

Comment: @Dominic. Sure you can do it that way. I sometimes do it that way myself. I even wrote a tool that allows one to regenerate the graphics without loosing the labels. See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132519/3066)

Comment: Added an alternative method for writing the line segment labels.