# Graphic drawn using Drawing Tools will not save properly

Tags: graphics

I have two very stubborn arrows that show up as green in a.png file I have saved (by right clicking and selecting 'save selection as') even though in the notebook interface I have edited them to be black. Yes, I tried deleting and redrawing the arrows entirely. And for anyone who sees this that also works at Wolfram, let me add that working with Drawing Tools is not very easy at times. It is very buggy.

Comment: Can't really help you beyond noting that you can post-process your drawn `Graphics` using Mathematica's standard destructuring methods (e.g. `Cases`) since my guess is that you want to be able to edit by hand for positioning, but styling is likely easier using programmatic methods. Basically you can use the drawing tools to get positions and then pull that data out using code so that you can make a well styled graphic

Comment: Perhaps you will find the tool described in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132519/3066) can help you.